# Can something be 'inviting' AND 'daunting'

Tags: word-usage

Can something be inviting and daunting? How mutually exclusive are the words inviting and daunting? I know that they are not as exclusive as "BRIGHT" and "DARK" (i.e. something cannot be both bright and dark), but what about 'inviting' and 'daunting'

Comment: Google **"inviting and daunting"**

Comment: It is a perfect description of many of my ex's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on how a person experiences that something.

For example an amusement park thrill-ride definitely can be both. Same for bungee-jumping, parachuting, base-jumping, cave-diving. For the thrill-seeker [extreme sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_sport) can be irresistible.

The name for it? **Challenge**.

---

[EDIT]
About parachuting, there's an article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachuting). From my personal experience, a guy I knew went skydiving for years and came to grief once ending in hospital. Almost before he was released he was back in the air, continuing with a lot of pleasure until a very serious, debilitating accident.

He now is banned because of the danger. But still would jump if given the chance.

Daunting? Oh yes.
Inviting? Irresistibly so.

Very disturbing to witness.

---

References

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_sport

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachuting

Comment: Can you please elaborate, using say, the example of parachuting?

Comment: Please include citations in plain text for those links - if they rot they'll take the readers of your answer no where.

Comment: A pleasure, @Little Eva. You keep us all safely linked.

Answer (score 0):

As per their dictionary meanings are concerned, yes they are mutually exclusive. I can't imagine using them in the same sentence otherwise the sentence itself would sound paradoxical.

Comment: This is no answer - it's a comment - it lacks definitions, examples of usage, support with citations to authority, links.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the combination is not an uncommon trope.  The words in tandem get hundreds of thousands of hits in the google.  Here's one that caught my eye from *The Inspired Wisdom of Abraham Lincoln* by Philip Ostergard:

```
Admittedly, early Americans like Lincoln had a strategic advantage,
entering a land with virgin forests and hills of minerals; a land
with ribbons of natural waterways simultaneously inviting and
daunting exploration.
```